# Share ppp connection on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, networkmanager, ppp, connection-sharing

I have internet on my Debian Stretch via ppp broadband usb modem. It works via Network Manager. There is no connection sharing option in Network Manager for ppp. It is only for ethernet.

How to achieve ppp internet connection sharing to ethernet? And this should be executed automatically at boot time and have dhcp for other computers.